# Do you recognize this infinite series? $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{(1+an)^c} \frac{b^n}{n!} $

Tags: calculus, power-series, special-functions

I came by this infinite series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac 1{(1+an)^c} \frac{b^n}{n!} $$

Is there some special function that can have this form?

$c$ can be assumed to be a positive integer. While $a,b$ are positive real numbers

Comment: Thanks this is interesting. But I am interested in the case where a is not necessarily integer.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function

Comment: The sum is equal to $$ \frac{1}{a^c \Gamma(c)} \int_{0}^{1} e^{bx} x^{(1/a)-1} \log^{c-1}(1/x) \, dx. $$ I am not sure if this simplifies further...

Comment: If there is any $f(x)$ that satisfies $f^{(n)}(0)=(1+an)^{-c}$, then the sum is equal to $f(b)$

Comment: When $c$ is a positive integer, the expression equals to a generalized hypergeometric function
${}_cF_c\left( \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_c ; \beta_1,\ldots,\beta_c; b\right)$ where all $\alpha_i = \frac1a$ and and all $\beta_i = \frac1a + 1$.